# SharePoint 2010 [SharePoint_ManagedMetadata].[dbo].[ECMChangeLog] growing out of control

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata, ecm

I am a DBA trying to manage the database back end of a very elderly and poorly maintained SharePoint 2010 application. I have almost no knowledge of the application or architecture other than that there are three sqlserver instances involved, LIVE, APP and CONTENT. I've identified an issue with the `[SharePoint_ManagedMetadata].[dbo].[ECMChangeLog]` growing out of control.  It appears that there are around 200 terms with in excess of 1000 changelog entries a day (out of a total list of 18000 terms), most appearing at the same time in the early morning so presumably the result of an automated job.  This is also causing very high network traffic.

My questions are:

1. would there be any issues around my clearing down the changelog table and how much should I retain in there?
2. what job or process would be responsible for all these changelog entries? There are all just generic intranet terms, department names and the like, can I just get the job stopped?
3. Why would there be so many hundreds of daily updates in the ECMChangelog table for each term?
4. Why are so few terms affected?  Could they be in some sort of group or associated with a particular area of content?  How would I find out?

I have done the obvious googling but can't find anybody with a similar issue.  The whole thing is being migrated fairly soon the aim is just to keep it limping along until end of life.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me, and apologies for my utter lack of SharePoint knowledge. I am quite happy to be told I am likely to do more harm than good and should leave it well alone.

Comment: DO NOT TOUCH SHAREPOINT DATABASES. They're blackboxes for you, as a DBA. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-products-and-by-windows-sharepoint-services-502c6da1-be7e-39b0-0ea8-8b4ebd44a374. I'm going to come back to this question later regarding potential causes but reminder SharePoint 2010 is _fully_ out of support. What patch level is the farm at?

Comment: Thanks, I will take your advice and back slowly away...  Not really my problem and it sounds as if I will only make things worse if I start poking it.  I have recommended to the applications team that we get rid of it ASAP but other than that I will leave it alone.